# Finding Share of Group Total for each element Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power Bi, I'd like a measure to get share of a group total for each element in that group. For example,

| Player | Team | Goals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rooney | MU | 3 |
| Ronaldo | MU | 2 |
| Rashford | MU | 5 |
| Crouch | SP | 5 |

So for Ronaldo, it would be 20% as it's his goals / team total

Crouch would be 100% etc

How could I do this in DAX?

Comment: How are you getting 40%?

Comment: @David He wanted to say 20%.

Answer (score 0):

```
VAR playersResult = SUM(tbl[Goals])
VAR teamResult = CALCULATE(SUM(tbl[Goals]),ALL(tbl[Player])
RETURN
    playersResult /teamResult
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Efficiency =
VAR GoalScored =
    SUM ( Club[Goals] )
VAR TeamScored =
    SUMX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE ( Club, Club[Player], Club[Team] ),
            "TeamScored", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Club[Goals] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Club, Club[Team] ) )
        ),
        [TeamScored]
    )
VAR Efficiency =
    DIVIDE ( GoalScored, TeamScored )
RETURN
    Efficiency
```

If we test it:

[image: FDGGG]